# iOS: Tapping on Facebook app login does not bring up allow/don't allow options for my app

Tags: iphone, facebook, sdk

Problem:
I run the sample iOS SDK code for facebook connect.  When Facebook app is not installed, the sample app authenticates through Safari just fine and the sample app is able to post successfully.

When native Facebook app is installed, the sample app causes the Facebook app to be launched for authentication which shows a page that is requesting login for the demo app. When I press the login, it brings up another window that has the allow/"don't allow" options.  So far so good.  The problem is that if I logout from within the sample app (i.e., [_facebook logout:self]) and try to login again, pressing the "login" button in the Facebook app does nothing (it's supposed to take you to the allow/"do not allow" page).

I have specified the App-ID in the sample app and I have included the fb[app-id] (e.g., fb1234) in the plist under 'URL Types' (otherwise, the Safari authentication would not have worked either).

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not take you again to the "allow/don't allow" page because the user already gave permission to the app. The only way the page can show again is when the user revoke the access from the Facebook admin panel. I'm not sure if there's a part of the API that can actually revoke the access of the app from the iOS SDK.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  You are correct.  The problem is that if I delete the app and re-install it, the app will attempt to authorize again (it doesn't have state) and Facebook app gets launched and we get stuck in the login.  Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: What do you mean with stuck in login?

Comment: Here is what I mean: App is authorized previously on Facebook.  We delete the app and re-install it on device.  App attempts to re-authorize. Facebook app launched and presents the login screen.  Tapping on the login triggers nothing because, as you pointed out, the app is already authorized in Facebook.  As a results Facebook app does not return control back to my app.

Comment: Weird because I just tried what you said and my Facebook dialog asked me to authorize the app again even though I authorized it from web. Maybe you should disable the Safari authorize when FB App is not installed, so you will always show the FB Dialog to Login/Authorize the user and it's done through a change on this line:   [self authorizeWithFBAppAuth:YES safariAuth:YES]; <- set the safariAuth to NO and it should do the trick. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for trying this. The problem does not seem to be Safari vs FB app. Plus, if FB app is not installed, the user would need a way to authorize and the above seem to disable that. Can you confirm that the FB app takes you to "allow/don't allow" screen after re-installing the FB Demo app (the one that uses GRAPH API) even if the Demo app has be authorized previously?  I tried this on two different iPhones with the same result (both get stuck on the login screen in FB app).  Thanks much for the help.

Comment: Oh well to be honest, didn't try it on device so I'm not sure if my "solution" will work on that. Which FB Demo App are you using? Because I have the default implementation of the API in my app and I did what I told you and still took me to the authorize page.

Comment: I just created a test Facebook account and the behavior is correct (as you mentioned).  Somehow, my main Facebook account behaves differently.  Thanks for all your help.  I marked the question as answered.